# Какие знаки препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки препинания в предложении: хотела уточнить во сколько завтра можно будет прийти за инвентарём

Comment: Подскажите, во сколько завтра можно забрать инвентарь.

Answer (score 0):

Хотела уточнить, во сколько завтра можно будет прийти за инвентарём.